# Count Unique Vaues with Criteria i.e. except some specific value

Tags: excel-formula, countif

There are 4 criteria I need to follow in order to count column B "unique values".
Criterion 1: Column A should be equal to "Cat B".
Criterion 2: Column B should not be equal to "N/A".
Criterion 3: Column B should not be equal to "TBD".
Criterion 4: Column B should not start with "D".

How to solve this problem?

Sample:

[image: Sample File]

Comment: is N/A text or an error message?

Comment: N/A is actually text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this array formula (click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> together) to get your result:

```
{=SUM(IF(--($A$2:$A$36="Cat B")*--($B$2:$B$36<>"N/A")*--(LEFT($B$2:$B$36,1)<>"D")*--($B$2:$B$36<>"TBD"),1/COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$36,$B$2:$B$36,$A$2:$A$36,"Cat B",$B$2:$B$36,"<>N/A",$B$2:$B$36,"<>D*",$B$2:$B$36,"<>TBD")),0)}
```

[image]

Just a note that `--` is to turn `TRUE/FALSE` to `1/0`.  It is easier to see in the `Evaluate Formula` window for debugging.  But you can remove those dashes to make the formula shorter if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try countifs

=COUNTIFS(A2:A150;"Cat B";B2:B150;"<>*N/A*";B2:B150;"<>D*";B2:B150;"<>TBD")

Generic formula fro cells that do not contain certain text is : =COUNTIF(rng,"<>*txt*")

Comment: After fixing those semicolon ";" in the formula =COUNTIFS(A2:A1000,"Cat B",B2:B1000,"<>N/A",B2:B1000,"<>D*",B2:B1000,"<>TBD") it is filtering out what we don't want to count but it is not counting unique values in column B.

Answer (score 0):

In `Cell C2` enter below formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$14,MATCH(1,INDEX(((COUNTIF($C$1:C1,$B$2:$B$14)=0)*($A$2:$A$14<>"Cat B")*($B$2:$B$14<>"N/A")*($B$2:$B$14<>"TBD")*(LEFT($B$2:$B$14,1)<>"D")),0,0),0)),"")
```

Drag/Copy down as required. Change range `$A$2:$A$14` and `$B$2:$B$14` as per your data range.

[image]

***EDIT :*** To get count of unique PIN use

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A845="Cat B")*(B2:B845<>"N/A")*(B2:B845<>"TBD")*(LEFT(B2:B845,1)<>"D")/COUNTIF(B2:B845,B2:B845))
```

Comment: Well, that is giving me unique values but here we are looking for COUNT of unique values which is going to be in one cell.

Comment: @NaseerAhmad - Oops! I missed that count at the beginning. See edit should be fine now.

Comment: we only need Cat B, so I have changed a part of the formula from ($A$2:$A$14<>"Cat B") to ($A$2:$A$14="Cat B") but still it is not giving me count of unique values.

Comment: @NaseerAhmad - Is there any particular pattern you think it's not working for because for my test data it seems to be giving correct result. Or else is it possible for you to share some sample data

Comment: @NaseerAhmad - You cannot attach files here, but you can upload it online and share the link here.

Comment: May be it is because you are using numbers in your data but I don't have just numbers. My sample data in column B is following:871670,
D 865414-B,
CL717A,
P02081,
TBD

Comment: @NaseerAhmad - No, this formula will work even for strings also not just numbers.

Comment: @NaseerAhmad - Or else instead of using this formula for your complete data why don't you try this for small set of data. Else sharing file will be the best option so that I can look into it.

Comment: Here is a link of my worksheet. Correct answer should be 189 which on 2nd Tab. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_1K71ULjx5SVkhtdEs0RDlKSzQ

Comment: Thanks for your effort Mrig. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @NaseerAhmad - I know you've accepted an answer but I've still updated formula under EDIT in my answer, check if it helps.